# DevOps or SQLDataFactory pipline to Manipulate SQL Backup

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

Currently I have a PowerShell solution that the client would want in Azure DevOps, I've highlighted the steps below and wanted to know if it's possible to achieve this in either Azure DevOps or SQL Data Factory.

1) Download Backup from Azure BLOB Storage
2) Within Pipeline / Package - Unpack and mount the file.
3) Truncate specific tables 
4) Backup to a different BLOB Container

or

1) Download Backup from Azure BLOB Storage to a SQL Server
2) Restore to a SQL Instance within the subscription
3) Truncate specific tables 
4) Backup to a different BLOB Container

Comment: The simple answer is that you can do anything in Azure Pipelines that you can script. So if you can create a PowerShell script that runs your steps you can put it in a pipeline. Azure DevOps can help you a bit with connecting to Azure (Service Endpoint) and there are some built in tasks to download and upload stuff to blob storage.

Comment: @WouterdeKort is it possible to do the restore within the Devops pipeline and truncate the SQL Data without having a Server dependancy?

Comment: No I don't think that's possible. Probably the easiest is to spin up a Docker container with SQL Server or use a SQL Azure environment that you can create and destroy during your pipeline.